# What philosophy did Nietzsche base his idea of "amor fati" on?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, nietzsche, determinism, stoicism

I've heard alot of people say that Nietzsche made his idea on amor fati from stoicism or stoic principles, is that true?

Comment: See [Anor fati](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amor_fati)

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Fidel Ferrer contextualises Nietzsche's various uses of *amor fati* in [German Philosophers: Kant, Hegel, Schelling, Nietzsche, and Heidegger](https://philpapers.org/rec/FERGPK), page 149, e.g.

> Nietzsche may have been contrasting *amor fati* to Spinoza’s *amor dei
> intellectualis*. Nietzsche’s own use of *amor fati* lines up (1881)
> when Nietzsche was reading Kuno Fischer’s book *Geschichte der neuern
> Philosophie* (1865), which includes a section on Spinoza.
>
> ...
>
> Nietzsche wrote, “Also I am in a mood of fatalistic “surrender to God”
> (Gottergebenheit) I call it *amor fati* so much so that I would have
> rush into a lion’s jaw not to mention — (Naumburg, ca. June 5, 1882:
> Letter to Franz Overbeck. *Selected letters of Friedrich Nietzsche*,
> 1969, page 184).”

Generally stoic.